# How do I ensure the VBA code saves the workbook to the file path declared?

Tags: vba, excel

The following is my code in an attempt to delete a number of sheets in order to save a workbook with specific worksheets only:

```
Sub SeperateWB2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheetname As Variant
Dim ddl As Variant

ddl = "PhaseTransferDropDowns"
sheetname = InputBox("Please specify sheet name:")
Path = "C:\My Documents\Phase Transfer\Test\"

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'SetVersions
    If Not ws.Name = sheetname And Not ws.Name = ddl Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws

wb.SaveAs Path & ws.Name & ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wb.Close
        Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

The loop works fine but it refuses to save the workbook on the path I have specified.

I get this message: "Runtime error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `Path = "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Phase Transfer\Test\"` but it may depend on your windows version and that has no error control to ensure that the path exists..

Comment: `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` probably

Comment: You would be better off copying the desired worksheet to no location. This creates a new workbook with the copied worksheet. Then use `activeworkbook.saveas ....`. Easier than deleting all other worksheets.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that but it caused my data validation to stop working so I found this to be the better solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your error message: **Object variable** or With block variable **not set**

It looks like you aren't able to save because you never instantiate your `wb` variable. Therefore `wb = Nothing`. You can't perform `SaveAs` on nothing. Try adding `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` below your declarations like so:

```
'other code
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheetname As Variant
Dim ddl As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
ddl = "PhaseTransferDropDowns"
'other code
```

Comment: Upvoted for the nice explanation of the error, but it appears OP wants to work against `ThisWorkbook`, which isn't necessarily the `ActiveWorkbook` - hence `wb` isn't even needed.

Comment: @Mat'sMug agreed. `wb` may just be to save keystrokes or created by habit.

Answer (score 1):

The `wb` object variable is never assigned to anything other than `Nothing`. But anyway you can use `ThisWorkook`, if you mean to save and close the workbook that contains the running code:

```
With ThisWorkbook
     .SaveAs Path & ws.Name & ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
     .Close
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

It seems that I needed to set the workbook properly (`Set wb = ThisWorkbook`).

I also needed to change `ws.name` into `sheetname`.

This is the code that worked at the end:

```
Sub SeperateWB2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheetname As Variant
Dim ddl As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

ddl = "PhaseTransferDropDowns"
sheetname = InputBox("Please specify sheet name:")
Path = "C:\My Documents\Phase Transfer\Test\"

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'SetVersions
    If Not ws.Name = sheetname And Not ws.Name = ddl Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws

wb.SaveAs Path & sheetname & ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        'wb.Close

End Sub
```